# Orbeon Forms without wizard view

Tags: orbeon

I use Orbeon Forms 2016.2 CE (*Starting Orbeon Forms 2016.2.201608230055 CE* in catalina.out).
As a new feature I saw the possibility to [disable the wizard view for a form](http://blog.orbeon.com/2016/08/orbeon-forms-20162.html):

> Whether the form uses the Wizard View. By default, the published form uses  the configuration set via properties. (doc)

The properties in `properties-local.xml` contains the wizard view as default:

```
    <property  as="xs:string"
               name="oxf.fr.detail.view.appearance.*.*"
               value="wizard" />
```

So in the form options menu  I set "never" as value for `wizard view`.
And looking at the metadata in the source there effectively is reported
`<wizard>false</wizard>`

But nonetheless the form uses the wizard view, see the screenshot at the end.

What I have to change to see the form without the wizard view?

Thanks

Content of **properties-local.xml**

```
<properties xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">
<property   as="xs:string"
            name="oxf.fr.detail.view.appearance.*.*"
            value="wizard" />
<property   as="xs:integer"
            name="oxf.fb.grid.max-columns"
            value="8" />

<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*"   value="postgresql"/>
<property as="xs:anyURI"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.postgresql.uri" value="/fr/service/postgresql"/>
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.postgresql.datasource" value="postgresql"/>
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.postgresql.create-flat-view" value="true"/>
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.postgresql.autosave" value="true"/>
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.postgresql.permissions" value="true"/>
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.postgresq.versioning" value="true"/>

<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.exist.active"  value="false"/>
</properties>
```

Metadata instance in the source:

```
        <!-- Metadata -->
        <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <metadata>
                <application-name>TEST</application-name>
                <form-name>test_no_wizard</form-name>
                <title xml:lang="en">test without  wizard</title>
                <description xml:lang="en"/>
                <wizard>false</wizard>
            </metadata>
        </xf:instance>
```

[form screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoqNq.png)

Comment: This should definitely work. I will give it a try with CE and report.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to achieve the goal to have not every form with the wizard view.
Instead of setting the wizard view as default in the `properties-local.xml` and than disabling it for some forms, I took the other way. I activated the wizard view only in the forms where this was desired.

So I deleted the `name="oxf.fr.detail.view.appearance.*.*"` property in the `properties-local.xml`.

```
<properties xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">
<property   as="xs:integer"
            name="oxf.fb.grid.max-columns"
            value="8" />

<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*"   value="postgresql"/>

<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.exist.active"  value="false"/>
</properties>
```

In this way the forms appear as default without the wizard view. And for the forms where the wizard view is desired, I set *always* in the forms setting, see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1GyB.png)